# Gcc warning for implicit undeclared header files

Tags: c++, gcc, header-files, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I'm learning C++ in Visual Studio Code. I have this simple code to generate a random number. Now I forgot to `#include` both `<time>` and `<cstdlib>`. However, the compilation was successful.
I've read that this may be "due to an implicit inclusion of those headers by your compiler's standard library".

Is it possible to actually **enable compiler warnings for implicit inclusion of header files**? I have also read the following, which doesn't feel right:

> There is no specific warning in most C++ compilers that is triggered specifically for missing header files.
> When you omit the explicit inclusion of a required header file, the behavior is generally not considered an error or warning by the compiler. Instead, the compiler relies on the implicit inclusion of headers through other included headers or the standard library implementation.

This is my `tasks.json`, where I've been trying  new [flags for warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) but none seem to address the issue:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-ftime-report",
                // "-ftime-report-details",
                "-Wall",
                "-Wextra",
                "-Wuninitialized",
                "-Wnarrowing",
                "-Wconversion",
                "-Wswitch",
                "-Wswitch-enum",
                "-Wpedantic",
                // "-Werror",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

> "I've read" means ChatGPT told me - I coulnd't find online documentation tho.

Comment: For context, I'm running GCC within WSL (Ubuntu). I can provide details for software versions and else if required.

Comment: You've read correctly.  There isn't a way to have GCC warn you if you did not include the header.  You'll only get an error if your other include files don't wind up including the missing include.

Comment: There are tools to do this, but the tools I'm aware of are based around LLVM (clang).

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard permits the standard library implementation to have one standard library header include another or have it import more standard library names than specified for that header. Without that permission it would be very difficult to reasonably implement the C++ standard library.

So if you are using something that is only declared in `<cstdlib>` according to the specification, but you include another standard library header, then that thing may be declared anyway. It is the programmer's responsibility to check the specification and include the correct standard library headers if portability (also with respect to standard library versions) must be assured.

Compilers do not have an internal mapping of all C++ header files to the library facilities they are guaranteed to provide according to the standard. No compiler that I am aware of has a warning for this. However, there may be external tools that are aware of this mapping.

Even if you manage to work it out for the standard library itself, you will however still have the exact same issue with user headers, your own ones as well as those from other libraries. For example if you have `#include<libA.h>`, then it is very likely that `libA.h` will include some standard library header and so will declare elements of the standard library which wouldn't have been declared otherwise because you forgot to add the correct `#include` in your file. Because `#include` is simple text replacement done in a preprocessing step, it would be tricky to track to which `#include` a declaration should be publicly attached to.

In the end, you can't generally rely on any tool. You need to verify it yourself. Or, depending on how much portability is an issue, you can simply wait until it fails to build on some system.